# Determine $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the solution (x,y) is unique

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, tangent-line

$$x^2-y+m \le 0$$
$$y^2-x+m \le 0$$
Which value in $mathbb{R}$ does $m$ take such that the above system has a unique solution of the form $(x,y)$

Comment: You should say what you have attempted and where you are blocked.  You are not a newcomer in Math SE :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since graphs of $y=x^2+m$ and of $x=y^2+m$ are symmetric in relation to the graph of $y=x$,

we'll get an unique solution, when $y=x$ is a tangent line to $y=x^2+m$.

Thus, the equation $x^2-x+m=0$ has one root, which happens for $m=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: [+1] Besides, allow me a little redactional comment. I would not say that 2 equations are symmetric ; I would turn the first sentence in the following way: "let $C_m$ and $D_m$ be the curves (parabolas) with resp. equation $y=x^2+m$ and $x=y^2+m$. As transformation $(x,y)\to(y,x)$, which is an orthogonal refelction on the line $L$ with equation $y=x$, exchanges $C_m$ and $D_m$, the contact condition of the two curves is on line L, which is thus tangent to $C_1$ in particular."

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you are right! But I think it's better to add "Graphs of $y=x^2+m$ and $x=y^2+m$ are symmetric" only. If you want, then you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's up to you to make the modification...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Try to draw a picture to see how the parabolas $y=x^2+m$ and $x=y^2+m$ change if you change $m$.